# If the integral of a non-negative function is $0$, then the function is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-verification, solution-verification

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Show that if $\int_a^bf(x)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(x)$. Since $\int_a^xf(x)+\int_x^bf(x)=\int_a^bf(x)=0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$, we have $\int_a^xf(x)=-\int_x^bf(x)$. But since $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, both $\int_a^xf(x)$ and $\int_x^bf(x)$ are positive. So $F(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x)=F'(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I think it is valid proof.

Comment: It looks correct, although a bit diverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is correct, though invoking the fundamental theorem for this result is a bit of an over-kill. If you like, think of how to approach it quite directly. If $f(x)> 0$ for some $x$, then by continuity you can find an interval about $x$ where the function is greater than $f(x)/2$ on that interval. What can you now say about the integral of the function on $[a,b]$?

Comment: And even using continuity is kind of an over-kill.

Comment: Is continuity even needed?

Comment: @Did can you elaborate please?

Comment: @vilma: Yes, continuity is needed. Otherwise, for instance, the function can be zero except at a single point.

Comment: Measurability yields $\{f\ne0\}$ of measure zero. And... well... continuity shows that this set is open, then the only open set of measure zero is $\varnothing$ hence we are done. Yes, continuity is needed for $\varnothing$.